# How to deserialize XML with the different tag names but the same subtags?

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xmlserializer

I have the following XML:

```
<Vehicle>
      <Type>
        <ISN>213123214</ISN>
        <Name>ddsd</Name>
      </Type>
      <RegNo>1234</RegNo>
      <Mark>
        <ISN>423434234</ISN>
        <Name>asdasd</Name>
      </Mark>
      <Model>
        <ISN>434234324324</ISN>
        <Name>asddsa</Name>
      </Model>
      <EstimatedPrice>
        <Amount>15000</Amount>
        <AmountPrev />
        <Currency>
          <Code>R</Code>
          <Name>RU</Name>
        </Currency>
      </EstimatedPrice>
</Vehicle>
```

Well, I am trying to deserialize this to the destination object using C#.
This is my target class:

```
public class Vehicle {
    [XmlElement("Type")]
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Mark")]
    public Mark Brand { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Model")]
    public Mark Brand { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("EstimatedPrice")]
    public Estimation Estimation { get; set; }
}
```

The question is how to deserialize attributes Mark, Model and Type correctly? Now I'm getting empty objects instead of data. I've tried to specify "Vehicle" as the root tag for this subclasses, but it doesn't had an effect.

P.S. Classes Mark, Model and Type are derived from the base class:

```
[Serializable]
public class ResponseItem
{
        [XmlElement("ISN")]
        string ISN { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Name")]
        string Name { get; set; }
}
```

For deserializing I'm using XmlSerializer class. All the tags with to subtags or with subtags with unique names are deserialized correctly.

What have I missed?

Thanks.

Comment: Show full and *valid* code. This doesn't even compile — see duplicated `public Mark Brand { get; set; }` property. Note that `[Serializable]` has **nothing** to do with XML serialization.

Comment: Ok, my fault. You can just remove the duplicated mark. It's enough for me if you give me an example with the only one field.

`class Mark : ResponseItem { }
class Type : ResponseItem { }`

Estimation is unneccessary too, so as the tag 'EstimatedPrice'.

Comment: I always define the XSD for the XML first, then using that use the XSD.exe tool from Microsoft to generate the classes to serialize and deserialize to.

Comment: @user3548735 Please **edit** your question and provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve It's especially important with XML serialization — the devil is in the detail, and usually deeply buried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties in your `ResponseItem` base class **must** be public

```
public class ResponseItem
{
    [XmlElement("ISN")]
    public string ISN { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

XML serializer won't process non-public properties

Comment: And that was the thing!

Answer (score 0):

I like working backwards and create a test serializer to validate my structures.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle() {
                Type = new Type()
                {
                    ISN = "213123214",
                    Name = "ddsd"
                },
                RegNo = 1234,
                Brand = new Mark()
                {
                    ISN = "423434234",
                    Name = "asdasd"
                },
                Model = new Mark()
                {
                    ISN = "434234324324",
                    Name = "asddsa"
                },
                estimation = new Estimation()
                {
                    Amount = 15000,
                    AmountPrev = null,
                    currency = new Currency()
                    {
                        Code = "R",
                        Name = "RU"
                    }
                }
            };

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Vehicle));

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, vehicle);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("Vehicle")]
    public class Vehicle
    {
        [XmlElement("Type")]
        public Type Type { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Mark")]
        public Mark Brand { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Model")]
        public Mark Model { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("RegNo")]
        public int RegNo { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("EstimatedPrice")]
        public Estimation estimation { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("EstimationPrice")]
    public class Estimation
    {

        [XmlElement("Amount")]
        public int Amount { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("AmountPrev")]
        public int? AmountPrev { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Currency")]
        public Currency currency { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("Currency")]
    public class Currency
    {
        [XmlElement("Code")]
        public string Code { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }


    [XmlRoot("Type")]
    public class Type : ResponseItem
    {
    }
    [XmlRoot("Mark")]
    public class Mark : ResponseItem
    {
    }

    [XmlRoot("ResponseItem")]
    public class ResponseItem
    {
        [XmlElement("ISN")]
        public string ISN { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
​
```